# How to get percentage of a column based on key in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have table like

```
Student_name,Subject
Ram,Maths
Ram,Science
Arjun,Maths
Arjun,Science
Arjun,Social
Arjun,Social
```

Output : I need to report only 'student' whose 'Social' subject percentage is more than 49%

```
Final output

Arjun, social, 50
```

.
    Temp output(backend)

```
Student_name,Subject,Percentage(group by student name)
Ram,Maths,50
Ram,Science,50
Arjun,Maths,25
Arjun,Science,25
Arjun,Social,50
```

I have tried with below awk commands but I see percentage on complete subjects irrespective group by student name.

```
awk -F, '{x++;}{a[$1,$2]++;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i],(a[i]/x)*100;}' OFS=, test1.csv > output2.dat

awk -F, '$2=="Science" && $3>=49{ print $1}' output2.dat
```

And Can we get it in single awk command.

Comment: Where are you even getting the percentages? You're not listing any useful inputs for AWK.

Answer (score 1):

Try following awk too once where it will provide the output in same order in which Input_file is data is there.

```
awk 'FNR>1 && FNR==NR{a[$1]++;b[$1]=$0;next} FNR==1 && FNR!= NR{print $0,"percentage";next}($1 in b){print $0"\t"100/a[$1]"%"}'   Input_file  Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Adding non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
FNR>1 && FNR==NR{
   a[$1]++;
   b[$1]=$0;
   next
}
FNR==1 && FNR!= NR{
   print $0,"percentage";
   next
}
($1 in b){
   print $0"\t"100/a[$1]"%"
}
'   Input_file  Input_file
```

**EDIT1:** Adding new solution as per OP's change in requirement.

```
awk '
FNR>1 && FNR==NR{
   a[$1]++;
   b[$1]=b[$1]?b[$1] ORS $0:$0;
   c[$1,$2];
   next
}
FNR==1 && FNR!= NR{
   print $0,"percentage";
   next
}
($1 in b){
   if($2=="Science" && (100/a[$1])>49){
     print b[$1]
}
}
'  Input_file Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks!! But could you please help me in modifiying the code as per changed source, And instead of displaying the output I need to report only student whose 'science' subject percentage is more than 49%

Comment: If you need the student values where science have more than 49, I have added EDIT2 now, let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks as mention in above comment, I have modified the source and desired output, can you please update the code for the same.

Comment: So EDIT1 is not helping you? because I added that condition where it should return only those records where science will have more than 49%, let me know on same.

Comment: It helped for filtering by subject , but in the input I have changed subject for arjun as social from english, now arjun should get 50% for social as we have two socials for arjun. (Can you tell me where to change the dilemeter to ,(comma) if we use source as csv.)

Answer (score 0):

GNU ***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{ print $0,"Percentage" }NR>1{ a[$1][$2]++ }
     END{ 
         for(i in a) for(j in a[i]) print i,j,(a[i][j]/length(a[i])*100"%")  
     }' OFS=',' test1.csv | column -t
```

The output:

```
Student_name,Subject,Percentage
Ram,Maths,50%
Ram,Science,50%
Arjun,Social,66.6667%
Arjun,Maths,33.3333%
Arjun,Science,33.3333%
```

Comment: I think there is some syntax error in the script, Could you please correct it!!

Comment: `syntax error The source line is 1.
 The error context is
                NR==1{ print $0,"Percentage" }NR>1{ >>>  a[$1][ <<<
 awk: The statement cannot be correctly parsed.`

Comment: @Bobby, please, update/extend your question with new conditions

Comment: @Bobby, I've change field separator, the new output is updated, no errors

Comment: Still I see the syntax error, Please modify with filter as mentioned in the updated question.

Comment: @Bobby, your expression with filter is another action which applied on the final result. But you told that you got errors with the first expression, while I don't have them. Add some screenshot

Comment: This is the error which am getting while executing the script  `syntax error The source line is 1.
 The error context is
                NR==1{ print $0,"Percentage" }NR>1{ >>>  a[$1][ <<<
 awk: The statement cannot be correctly parsed.
 The source line is 1.
 syntax error The source line is 3. ksh[4]: column:  not found`

Comment: And in your ouput, the complete 'Arjun' is getting more than 100% (66.66%+33.33%+33.33%) which should not be!

Comment: I do not know how to a attach the screenshot of the error here!!

Comment: upload your image to free image hosting, then, paste the link here

Comment: I cannot add the screenshot now., Could you please update the script based on above error which I have posted! And in your ouput, the complete 'Arjun' is getting more than 100% (66.66%+33.33%+33.33%) which should not be!

Comment: @Bobby, if my answer is not usefull - I'll delete it

Comment: No, your answer is so close to my result, In the output for a student the complete percentage is more that 100%

Answer (score -1):

### Use a Numeric Comparison

You can do this with a very simple numeric comparison against the third field:

```
$ awk '$3 > 49 {print}' /tmp/input 
Student_name    Subject     Percentage(group by student name)
Ram             Maths       50%
Ram             Science     50%
```

For this comparison, AWK coerces to a string, so the comparion will treat `50%` the same as `50`. As a nice byproduct, if the third field doesn't contain any numbers then it does a string comparison. The header line is greater than `!` so it matches, too.

Comment: Is there any change need to be done for the first awk?

Comment: The issue is with first awk command , which i have posted, I am not getting 50% for Ram , it is calculating the percentage on complete occurrence subjects